# Bockstein cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, differential-graded-algebras

There is a notion of [Bockstein homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bockstein_homomorphism) $\beta$. I am interested precisly in the case of sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \rightarrow 0$$

Wikipedia says that $\beta^2 = 0$. So we can consider cohomology of $\beta$. The chains of this complex are cohomology $H^i ( X, \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} ) $ and $\beta$ is the differential. Moreover this cohomology has structure of $dg$ algebra (usual cohomology has such structure and $\beta$ is a differential).

This cohomology is neither zero (for instance there are spaces with no odd cohomology as $\mathbb{CP^n}$) nor coincides with usual cohomology (as far as $\beta$ is not 0).

**Question** Did anybody consider this cohomology? Do you know any statments or references about it? Do they have a name?

This question is duplicated from math stack exchange, where it got no response.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1528408/bockstein-cohomology

Comment: Maybe Hatcher's algebraic topology's proposition 3E.3 is what you want.

Comment: This is the $E_1$ term of the standard cohomology Beckstein spectral sequence.  Many sources.  Nearest one to my hand is page 481 in http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/TEAK/KateBookFinal.pdf

Comment: I asked this question for $p=2$ at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73889/sq1-cohomology-of-spaces and got some interesting responses.